# weird offset with linerenderer and edgecollider

Tags: unity-game-engine

`enter code here`Hello im trying to make a laser but the collider as a weird offset from the collider. I tried moving some object out of the parent but it didnt changed anything. The only place where it works properly is 0,0,0.

[image: here is the weird offset]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Laser : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] public float defDistanceRay = 100;
    public Transform laserFirePoint;
    public LineRenderer m_lineRenderer;
    public Transform m_transform;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        ShootLaser();
    }

    void ShootLaser(){
        if(Physics2D.Raycast(m_transform.position, transform.right)){
            RaycastHit2D _hit = Physics2D.Raycast(laserFirePoint.position, transform.right);                       

            Draw2DRay(laserFirePoint.position, _hit.point);
    }

        else{
            Draw2DRay(laserFirePoint.position, laserFirePoint.transform.right * defDistanceRay);
        }
}

void Draw2DRay(Vector2 startPos, Vector2 endPos) {
    m_lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, startPos);
    m_lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, endPos);
    }

 }
```

This code made it work properly whitout before I added this code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Laser_collision : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LineRenderer LineRenderer;
    public EdgeCollider2D collider;
    void Update(){
        int pointcount = LineRenderer.positionCount;
        Vector2[] points = new Vector2[pointcount];

        for(int i = 0; i < pointcount; i++){
            points[i] = LineRenderer.GetPosition(i);
        }
        
        collider.points = points;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: Please consider adding more information as well as a reproducible example of your issue.

Comment: My best guess, with the info provided, is your linerenderer uses world-space coordinates and the edge collider you create in code interprets them as local-space. So you have to either offset the collider coordinates or switch the linerenderer to useWorldSpace = false